# Spring kubernetes configuration watcher not refreshing application after ConfigMap change

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes

So I've been struggling with this few days. I'm trying to hot reload a `spring boot` app after `configmap` changes.

The change is detected but it doesn't seem to refresh.

I did what exactly what was done in this project https://github.com/energy2522/spring-cloud-k8s-watcher-test/tree/main

The logs:

```
sClientEventBasedConfigMapChangeDetector : ConfigMap my-app-configmap was updated in namespace default
2023-08-29T13:34:18.651Z INFO 1 --- [ool-22-thread-1] o.s.c.k.c.watcher.WatcherUtil : will schedule remote refresh based on apps : [my-app]
2023-08-29T13:34:18.651Z DEBUG 1 --- [ool-22-thread-1] o.s.c.k.c.watcher.WatcherUtil : Scheduling remote refresh event to be published for config-map: with appName : my-app to be published in 120000 milliseconds
2023-08-29T13:34:18.652Z DEBUG 1 --- [ool-14-thread-1] s.c.k.c.c.ConfigMapPropertySourceLocator : Config Map normalized sources : [{ config-map name : 'Optional[spring-cloud-kubernetes-configuration-watcher]', namespace : 'Optional.empty', prefix : '[ConfigUtils.Prefix@2756c0a7 name = 'DEFAULT']' }]
2023-08-29T13:34:18.652Z DEBUG 1 --- [ool-14-thread-1] o.s.c.k.client.KubernetesClientUtils : configmap namespace from provider : null
2023-08-29T13:34:18.679Z DEBUG 1 --- [ool-14-thread-1] .c.k.c.c.KubernetesClientConfigMapsCache : Loaded all config maps in namespace 'default'
2023-08-29T13:34:18.679Z DEBUG 1 --- [ool-14-thread-1] s.c.k.c.c.ConfigMapPropertySourceLocator : paths property sources : []
2023-08-29T13:34:18.679Z DEBUG 1 --- [ool-14-thread-1] o.s.c.k.c.c.reload.ConfigReloadUtil : environment from locateMapPropertySources : ApplicationReactiveWebEnvironment {activeProfiles=[kubernetes], defaultProfiles=[default], propertySources=[MapPropertySource {name='server.ports'}, ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertySource {name='configurationProperties'}, PropertiesPropertySource {name='systemProperties'}, OriginAwareSystemEnvironmentPropertySource {name='systemEnvironment'}, RandomValuePropertySource {name='random'}, CachedRandomPropertySource {name='cachedrandom'}, MapPropertySource {name='KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE_PROPERTY_SOURCE'}, MapPropertySource {name='springCloudClientHostInfo'}, CompositePropertySource {name='composite-configmap', propertySources=[KubernetesClientConfigMapPropertySource@1439684156 {name='configmap.spring-cloud-kubernetes-configuration-watcher.default', properties={}}]}, CompositePropertySource {name='composite-secrets', propertySources=[]}, OriginTrackedMapPropertySource {name='Config resource 'class path resource [application.yml]' via location 'optional:classpath:/''}, MapPropertySource {name='spring.integration.poller'}, MapPropertySource {name='kafkaBinderDefaultProperties'}, {name='Management Server'}]}
2023-08-29T13:34:18.679Z DEBUG 1 --- [ool-14-thread-1] o.s.c.k.c.c.reload.ConfigReloadUtil : sources from locateMapPropertySources : [KubernetesClientConfigMapPropertySource@525016670 {name='configmap.spring-cloud-kubernetes-configuration-watcher.default', properties={}}]
2023-08-29T13:34:18.679Z DEBUG 1 --- [ool-14-thread-1] o.s.c.k.c.c.reload.ConfigReloadUtil : environment from findPropertySources: ApplicationReactiveWebEnvironment {activeProfiles=[kubernetes], defaultProfiles=[default], propertySources=[MapPropertySource {name='server.ports'}, ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertySource {name='configurationProperties'}, PropertiesPropertySource {name='systemProperties'}, OriginAwareSystemEnvironmentPropertySource {name='systemEnvironment'}, RandomValuePropertySource {name='random'}, CachedRandomPropertySource {name='cachedrandom'}, MapPropertySource {name='KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE_PROPERTY_SOURCE'}, MapPropertySource {name='springCloudClientHostInfo'}, CompositePropertySource {name='composite-configmap', propertySources=[KubernetesClientConfigMapPropertySource@1439684156 {name='configmap.spring-cloud-kubernetes-configuration-watcher.default', properties={}}]}, CompositePropertySource {name='composite-secrets', propertySources=[]}, OriginTrackedMapPropertySource {name='Config resource 'class path resource [application.yml]' via location 'optional:classpath:/''}, MapPropertySource {name='spring.integration.poller'}, MapPropertySource {name='kafkaBinderDefaultProperties'}, {name='Management Server'}]}
2023-08-29T13:34:18.679Z DEBUG 1 --- [ool-14-thread-1] o.s.c.k.c.c.reload.ConfigReloadUtil : environment sources from findPropertySources : [MapPropertySource {name='server.ports'}, ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertySource {name='configurationProperties'}, PropertiesPropertySource {name='systemProperties'}, OriginAwareSystemEnvironmentPropertySource {name='systemEnvironment'}, RandomValuePropertySource {name='random'}, CachedRandomPropertySource {name='cachedrandom'}, MapPropertySource {name='KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE_PROPERTY_SOURCE'}, MapPropertySource {name='springCloudClientHostInfo'}, CompositePropertySource {name='composite-configmap', propertySources=[KubernetesClientConfigMapPropertySource@1439684156 {name='configmap.spring-cloud-kubernetes-configuration-watcher.default', properties={}}]}, CompositePropertySource {name='composite-secrets', propertySources=[]}, OriginTrackedMapPropertySource {name='Config resource 'class path resource [application.yml]' via location 'optional:classpath:/''}, MapPropertySource {name='spring.integration.poller'}, MapPropertySource {name='kafkaBinderDefaultProperties'}, {name='Management Server'}]
2023-08-29T13:34:18.679Z DEBUG 1 --- [ool-14-thread-1] o.s.c.k.c.c.reload.ConfigReloadUtil : findPropertySources : [configmap.spring-cloud-kubernetes-configuration-watcher.default]
2023-08-29T13:34:18.679Z DEBUG 1 --- [ool-14-thread-1] o.s.c.k.c.c.reload.ConfigReloadUtil : no changes found, reload will not happen
2023-08-29T13:34:18.679Z DEBUG 1 --- [ool-14-thread-1] o.s.c.k.c.c.reload.ConfigReloadUtil : No change detected in config maps/secrets, reload will not happen
```

Any idea would be super helpful.
Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and I've also been struggling for several days. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: no unfortunately i didn't